# Import white house android open source fail?

Tags: java, android

I java use the file-import-Existing Android Code Into Workspace.Then add the ActionBarSherlock,undergarment,ViewPageIndicato as it's libary.Then fix it's properties.Everything is fine before i launch the AVD.Here is it's error information.

09-24 18:13:36.441: E/AndroidRuntime(588): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-24 18:13:36.441: E/AndroidRuntime(588): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application gov.whitehouse.ui.WhiteHouseApplication: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Application configuration is invalid.
09-24 18:13:36.441: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3957)
09-24 18:13:36.441: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:123)
09-24 18:13:36.441: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1185)
09-24 18:13:36.441: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-24 18:13:36.441: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-24 18:13:36.441: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-24 18:13:36.441: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-24 18:13:36.441: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-24 18:13:36.441: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-24 18:13:36.441: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-24 18:13:36.441: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-24 18:13:36.441: E/AndroidRuntime(588): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Application configuration is invalid.
09-24 18:13:36.441: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at com.urbanairship.UAirship.takeOff(Unknown Source)
09-24 18:13:36.441: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at gov.whitehouse.ui.WhiteHouseApplication.onCreate(WhiteHouseApplication.java:74)
09-24 18:13:36.441: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:969)
09-24 18:13:36.441: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3954)
09-24 18:13:36.441: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  ... 10 more

Do anyone has succeeed ? Any replay will be a good help.

Comment: Can you try to explain what your app is supposed to do? maybe show some code?

Comment: Hey,it likes what the title saying.It's the american white house android opensource project which is released in the github. https://github.com/WhiteHouse/wh-app-android

Comment: What is an undergarment?

Comment: Just the the external library likes ActionBarSherlock.